# Pandas search lower and upper neighbour within group

Tags: pandas, group-by, nearest-neighbor

I have the following dataframe df, which specifies latitudes and longitudes for a certain groupnumber:

```
      latitude   longitude   group
0    51.822231   4.700267    1
1    51.822617   4.801417    1
2    51.823235   4.903300    1
3    51.823433   5.003917    1
4    51.823616   5.504467    1
5    51.822231   3.900267    2
6    51.822617   3.901417    2
7    51.823235   3.903300    2
8    51.823433   6.903917    2
9    51.823616   8.904467    2
10   51.822231   1.900267    3
11   51.822617   2.901417    3
12   51.823235   11.903300   3
13   51.823433   12.903917   3
14   51.823616   13.904467   3
```

Within each groupnumber I try to find the lower and upper neighbour of the column 'longitude' for a specified value longitude_value = 5.00. All longitudes within each group 'trips' are sorted in df (they ascend in each group)

Per row I want to have the upper and lower neighbour values of longitude=5.000000. The desired output looks like:

```
      latitude   longitude   trip
2    51.823235   4.903300    1
3    51.823433   5.003917    1
7    51.823235   3.903300    2
8    51.823433   6.903917    2
11   51.822617   2.901417    3
12   51.823235   11.903300   3
```

From this result I want to rearrange the data a little bit as:

```
     lat_lo     lat_up        lon_lo     lon_up  
0    51.823235  51.823433     4.903300   5.003917            
1    51.823235  51.823433     3.903300   6.903917        
2    51.822617  51.823235     2.901417   11.903300
```

Comment: Question no clear. Could you explain what you mean by =5.00. Maybe increase the length of output so that we understand how you filter data to realise outcome.

Comment: I edited the question. I hope it is clear now

Comment: Was my solution helpful or you need some improvements?

Comment: For what I ve seen it looks like it is what I needed. Later this week I ll thoroughly check if its works for my much longer dataset. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope I got your question right. See my attempt below. Made it long to be explicit in my approach. I could have easily introduced a longitude value of 5.00 and sliced on index but that would have complicated answering part 2 of your question. If I missed something, let me know.

Data

```
df=pd.read_clipboard()
df
```

[image]

Input point and calculate difference with longitude

```
fn=5.00
df['dif']=(df['longitude']-fn)
df
```

Find the minimum positive difference in each group

```
df1=df[df['dif'] > 0].groupby('group').min().reset_index().reindex()
```

Find the minimum negative difference in each group

```
df2=df[df['dif'] < 0].groupby('group').max().reset_index().reindex()
```

[Append](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) the second group above to the first into one df. **This answers your question 1**

```
df3=df1.append(df2, ignore_index=True).sort_values(['group','longitude'])
df3
```

**Question 2**

Introduce a column called `status` and append a pattern, `3` for the lower neighbor and `4` for the upper neighbor

```
df3['Status']=0
np.put(df3['Status'], np.arange(len(df3)), ['3','4'])
df3.drop(columns=['dif'], inplace=True)
df3
```

[Rename](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) the neighbours to `lon_lo` and `lon_up`

```
df3['Status']=np.where(df3['Status']==3,'lon_lo', (np.where(df3['Status']==4,'lon_up',df3['Status'] )))
```

Using [pivot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html), break up the dataframe into `lon_lo` and latitude and do the same to `lon_up`. The rational here is to break up `latitude`s into two groups `lo` and `up`

first group break

```
df4=df3[df3['Status']=='lon_lo']
result=df4.pivot_table('longitude',['latitude','group'],'Status').reset_index().set_index('group')
```

second group break

```
df4=df3[df3['Status']=='lon_up']
result1=df4.pivot_table('longitude',['latitude','group'],'Status').reset_index().set_index('group')
```

[Merge on index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) the two groups while renaming the `latitude`s to `lo` and `up`

```
final=result1.merge(result, left_index=True, right_index=True, suffixes=('_lo','_up'))
final
```

Output

[image]